# Compute the norm of $f: \ell_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ define by $f(x)=x_1+x_2-x_4+x_5-ix_{80}$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Define $f: \ell_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $f(x)=x_1+x_2-x_4+x_5-ix_{80}$ is $f$ continous? compute $||f||$

This is my atemp:

Note that $$f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)+f_4(x)+f_5(x)+f_{80}(x)$$
where
$f_1(x)=x_1$,
$f_2(x)=x_2$,
$f_4(x)=-x_4$,
$f_5(x)=x_5$,
$f_{80}(x)=ix_{80}$
is clear than the $f'is$ are linear and bounded and therefore continous and how $f$ is the sum of $f'is$ these implies than $f$ is continous.

Now considerer $e_1$ then $||e_1||_2=1$ and $|f(e_1)|=1$ these implies that $1 \leq ||f||$ but i have problems to show the other inequality.

Any hint or suggestion i will very grateful, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hints: Cauchy-Schwarz inequlity shows that $|f(x)| \leq \|x\|\sqrt {1+1+1+1+1}$ so $\|f\| \leq \sqrt 5$. Now consider $(1,1,-1,1,i,0,0...0)$ to show that $\|f\| \geq \sqrt 5$. So $\|f||=\sqrt 5$.

Comment: As usual short and precise.$+1$

Comment: @LostinSpace Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: To compute $\|f\|$, first write $f(x) = \langle e_1+e_2-e_4+e_5-ie_{80},x\rangle$, and then use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality to bound $|f(x)| \le ?\|x\|$. You'll then get that $\|f\| = ?$ if you can show that equality holds for some non-zero $x$.